# Чем std::unique_lock отличается от std::lock_guard?

Tags: c++, синхронизация, c++14

Чем std::unique_lock отличается от std::lock_guard? В каких ситуациях лучше применять один класс, а в каких другой?

Comment: Отличия детально расписаны в [справочнике](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread), `unique_lock` приминяется, когда есть необходимость передачи владения или вызова других методов, отсутствующих в `lock_guard`.

Comment: @VTT, наличие ответа в неком мане не делает вопрос плохим.

Comment: @vp_arth В данном случае делает, потому что вопрос (1) слишком широкий, так как на перечисление отличий уйдет не один десяток страниц (2) [noresearch](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20516773/2110496

Comment: @VTT, это был технический комментарий. [тема на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4409/176064)

Comment: У unique_lock более широкий функционал, а значит бОльшие накладные расходы.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lock_guard` и `unique_lock` - почти то же самое. Разница в том, что вы можете заблокировать и разблокировать `std :: unique_lock`. `std :: lock_guard` будет заблокирован только один раз при построении и разблокирован при уничтожении.

- [lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard): когда объект создан, он пытается получить мьютекс
  (вызывая `lock()`), а когда объект уничтожен, он автоматически
  освобождает мьютекс (вызывая `unlock()`).
- [unique_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock): также поддерживает отложенную блокировку, временную блокировку, рекурсивную блокировку и использование условных переменных.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516773/stdunique-lockstdmutex-or-stdlock-guardstdmutex)

Comment: Почему тогда просто всегда не использовать unique_lock? В каком случае мне предпочитать lock_guard?

Comment: *почти то же самое* - ну это вы загнули... `lock_guard` и `unique_lock` - это скорее как мыльница и зеркальный фотоаппарат

Comment: Фактически, я бы сказал, нет разницы. Используйте `lock_guard`, если не нужны фишки `unique_lock`. Как самый простой пример, большей функциональности требуется больше вычислительных затрат. Некоторые функции требуют `unique_lock`, также, насколько мне известно, `unique_lock` используется для большей параллелизации кода, некоторые потоки могут ждать блокировки мьютекса и ничего не делать в это время.

Comment: @mrFieldy Я может не внимательно прочитал ответы и комментарии, но самого главного кажется не сказали -  `lock_guard` в первую очередь используется для [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

Таким образом, если вам нужен `RAII` (то есть чтобы при выходе из функции или генерировании `exception` гарантированно освобождался mutex) - используйте `std::lock_guard`. Гарантированно - в смысле вы будете уверены что не забыли нигде освободить mutex.

Comment: @vegorov А std::unique_lock разве не RAII? Просто я везде в коде использовал его как будто он RAII >_<.

Comment: @mrFieldy им можно пользоваться как `RAII`,  но вы можете его блокировать и разблокировать, а вот `std::lock_guard` - нет, `mutex` будет заблокирован при построении `std::lock_guard`, и разблокирован при уничтожении, как и написали в ответе. Когда Вам нужен просто `RAII`, используйте `std::lock_guard`. Когда Вам нужна дополнительная функциональность(например, заблокировать два мьютекса) - `std::unique_lock`